# how do i invoke Z3 Programmatically

Tags: z3

Hi I am new to Z3 SMT solver. I know you can invoke Z3 programmatically by using relevant APIs. But I want to do the following things with Z3 SMT solver:

1. how can I feed Z3 with one input file programmatically?
2. how can I incrementally get the solution(s)?

For example:

```
while ((check-sat) returns sat)
  get the assignments for all boolean vairables
```

Finally, how can I ask Z3 to save the results into one output file after solving the formula?

Any ideas or documents I can look at?

Thanks million!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Z3 distribution contains several (programmatic API) examples.

- examples/c/test_capi.c: many small examples using the C interface.
- examples/dotnet/test_managed.cs: similar examples in C#
- examples/maxsat/maxsat.c: MaxSAT procedures (in C) on top of the Z3 API.
- examples/ocaml/test_mlapi.ml: examples in ML
- examples/theory/test_user_theory.c: example showing how to implement an external theory (plugin).

Comment: hey i tried to use Z3_parse_smtlib2_file API to read in an input smt2 file then used check API. But Z3 gave me the unexpected result. Am I missing something before using the check API(after finish parsing)? Is there a full example with Z3_parse_smtlib2_file API?

Comment: The function Z3_parse_smtlib2_file returns a pointer to an expression containing all assertions in the SMT 2.0 file. The assertion is not asserted into the Z3 context. The user is responsible for invoking Z3_assert_cnstr. The example `parser_example1` shows how to do it. The example is for `Z3_parse_smtlib_string`, but the idea is the same.